# Listening English Skill

Tags: listening

I can read and understand technical English, but I have difficulty understanding what I hear. What can I do to improve my listening skill? Please help!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I'm not sure that this is the best place for this question  - have you tried the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) site? Meanwhile, I'd suggest you just need more practice. If you have access to recorded speech, even movies and TV, try to find a published script and listen while reading what you're hearing. Some dialects and accents make comprehension harder than others, so try to find examples of the ones you're most likely to come across in daily life.

Comment: If someone had difficulty in parking reverse, what would you advise them to do? If someone didn't know how to dance the foxtrot, what should they do? If someone knew how a bicycle worked, understood its dynamics but couldn't ride one going uphill, what would you say? I would say: Practice, practice, practice... English on the radio, on DVDs, on CDs, MP3s, on your iPhone (Siri?), self-record yourself etc.

Comment: Listen to films and TV - on the Internet if you cannot get hold of them locally. And as @Mari-LouA said, try to speak and listen at every opportunity. (And as I found when teaching ESL long ago, beer can help language learners, by reducing their inhibitions and embarrassment!)

Answer (score 2):

Let me recommend **watching English movies with English subtitles**.

This will leverage your existing reading skills, and **your mind will gradually get accustomed to match what you see (on-screen subtitles) with what you hear the actors say**.

This is basically what the audio-visual method is all about, and it's known to be very effective for improving both listening and speaking skills.

Comment: I would like to add another thing that helped me.
Listening to English music. I would recommend Pop, R&B , because of the slow vocals (but its your choice). 

Try to listen to a song and write the lyrics for it and then compare them with the actual lyrics of the song.
And if there are a few things you didn't get right, go back and listen to the song again and how the word is being pronounced. 

This really helped me apart from watching movies as @A.P. already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

One word: **Alcohol**

When I was learning German, I used to watch the news on Deutsche Welle every night before bed. I finally had a breakthrough one night while I was having a glass of wine during the show - suddenly my comprehension increased from about 30% to about 80%. Surprisingly, the increased ability persists to this day.

My theory is that the alcohol helped me stop getting hung up on each word. Afterwards, I could let the words just be absorbed as they came.

Viel Glück!

Comment: [British Beer AKA Instant English](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/07/c6/9b/07c69b1c18e4ba493c60f4f6c74af1d1.jpg) :)